# Can't save uploaded data

Tags: php, html

This is my PHP Code:

```
$uploaddir = 'new/';
$x = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['x']['name']);
$a = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['a']['name']); 
$b = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['b']['name']); 
$c = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['c']['name']); 
$d = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['d']['name']); 
$e = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['e']['name']); 
$f = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['f']['name']); 
$g = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['g']['name']); 
$h = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['h']['name']); 

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['x']['tmp_name'], $x)) {
header("Location: collage.php?x=$x&a=$a&b=$b&c=$c&d=$d&e=$e&f=$f&g=$g&h=$h");} else {
echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
```

This PHP code's purpose is to save the uploaded image. But my problem is, it's only saving the 1st upload image.

Comment: It's because you're moving only the first file.

Comment: How can i move all of them?

Comment: Put the move_uploaded_file() inside a loop and call it for all the files

Comment: Can u give me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is not a perfect solution, I don't understand why you names the files as alphabets.

```
$uploaddir = 'new/';

$files = new array ('x','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileName = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
    $path = $uploaddir . $fileName;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        header("Location: collage.php?x=$x&a=$a&b=$b&c=$c&d=$d&e=$e&f=$f&g=$g&h=$h");
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed";
    }
}
```

You can use this :

```
foreach( $_FILES as $fieldname => $file ) {
    move_uploaded_file( $file[tmp_name], $path );
}
```

Comment: It's because i need to send the data through get and so get only supported 2000 chr. So i use alphabets to short it.

Comment: Can u also modify the code and make it to rename each file (if exist then try next..) and then save it. Please...

Comment: modified the code, hashing the filename to get unique string

Comment: How does this code rename each file and what if the name already exist. Can u please explain.

Comment: A hash function will always generate a unique string for a particular file, hence it will make sure you don't upload duplicate files. If you upload a duplicate file, it will generate the same string and hence replace the same file. So avoid redundancy.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Definitely, Can I talk with u on facebook, I have some words with you.

Comment: There is syntex error on your first, code. Unexpected '['

Comment: But still its showing error syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' (on that line)

Comment: The hash method is increaseing file's name lenth and deleteing extention. Can u please remove the renameing process from code. This will be that last time I'll bother u...

Comment: Removed the hashing part